# How can I change Sprite Image every half a second?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have been trying to achieve this from this morning but haven't figured it out. I have a SKSpriteNode which is an Image that displays the name of my game on the main screen. What I am trying to achieve is to change those images every half a second. I have made multiple images of the name with different colors so I can change images every half a second.That will give the effect of the title changing colors like a typical arcade game. This is what I have done so far...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"YellowLabel.png", @"BlueLabel.png", @"GreenLabel.png", @"RedLabel.png", @"WhiteLabel.png", nil];

    NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(doAnimation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [TitleScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    SKSpriteNode *labelNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"WhiteLabel.png"];
    labelNode.position = CGPointMake(160, 400);

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
    [self doAnimation];
    [scene addChild:labelNode];
}
```

And I also have this additional method:

```
-(void)doAnimation {
    SKSpriteNode *labelNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"WhiteLabel.png"];
    static int counter = 0;
    if ([_images count] == counter+1) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    labelNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:[_images objectAtIndex:counter]];
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do this with `SKAction` :

```
SKAction *actionWait = [SKAction waitForDuration:.5];
SKAction *actionBlock = [SKAction runBlock:^(void)
{
    // do whatever you want to do every half second here
}];

SKAction *actionSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[actionWait, actionBlock]];
SKAction *actionRepeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:actionSequence]
[self runAction:actionRepeat];
```

Another way, could be like this, since I think you are just animating textures :

```
// create an NSArray called anim that includes all your SKATextures

SKAction *actionAnimate = [SKAction animateWithTextures:anim timePerFrame:.5 resize:YES restore:NO];
SKAction *actionRepeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:actionAnimate];
[self runAction:actionRepeat];
```

Comment: Why does it say Use of Undeclared Indentifier right away when I paste your code?

Comment: Which line ? Maybe a typo,  but this is not something you can cut/paste without having to account for your own implementation. It's an example. Did you create a NSArray with your textures ? That will likely result in an error if you didn't do what my code comment said : 'create an NSArray called anim that includes all your SKATextures'

Comment: Great! Making progress now! Now in your second method on the last line where is says [self runAction:actionRepeat]; it says No visible @interface. Am I supposed to change it to something else that I might have in my code?

Comment: Where is the code ? sounds like you have it in your ViewController. The code needs to be in your scene. Also, you should take a look at reference for SKAction for details on how to use them. They are an important aspect of SpriteKit, and are used for far more than something like this.